# How to identify specific strings within a text file?

Tags: r

I have a text file with the sequence of some proteins:
For example:

```
sp | P30044 | PRDX5_HUMAN Peroxiredoxin-5, mitochondrial OS = Homo sapiens OX = 9606 GN = PRDX5 PE = 1 SV = 4
MGLAGVCALRRSAGYILVGGAGGQSAAAAARRYSEGEWASGGVRSFSRAAAAMAPIKVGD
AIPAVEVFEGEPGNKVNLAELFKGKKGVLFGVPGAFTPGCSKTHLPGFVEQAEALKAKGV
QVVACLSVNDAFVTGEWGRAHKAEGKVRLLADPTGAFGKETDLLLDDSLVSIFGNRRLKR
FSMVVQDGIVKALNVEPDGTGLTCSLAPNIISQL

sp | P04083 | ANXA1_HUMAN Annexin A1 OS = Homo sapiens OX = 9606 GN = ANXA1 PE = 1 SV = 2
MAMVSEFLKQAWFIENEEQEYVQTVKSSKGGPGSAVSPYPTFNPSSDVAALHKAIMVKGV
DEATIIDILTKRNNAQRQQIKAAYLQETGKPLDETLKKALTGHLEEVVLALLKTPAQFDA
DELRAAMKGLGTDEDTLIEILASRTNKEIRDINRVYREELKRDLAKDITSDTSGDFRNAL
LSLAKGDRSEDFGVNEDLADSDARALYEAGERRKGTDVNVFNTILTTRSYPQLRRVFQKY
TKYSKHDMNKVLDLELKGDIEKCLTAIVKCATSKPAFFAEKLHQAMKGVGTRHKALIRIM
VSRSEIDMNDIKAFYQKMYGISLCQAILDETKGDYEKILVALCGGN
```

I would like to look for specific sequence strings, such as "DEATIIDILTK" or "DAIPAVEVFEGEPGNK" and wanted to know what are the two letters that come before these strings? Is it possible to do this in R? What are the best functions?

Thanks in advance

Kisses

Comment: what have you found so far?

Comment: Your first match (deatiidiltk) is at the beginning of a line, so there are no letters before it. Are you implying that all lines should be concatenated with no intervening space? That is, the second one is `sp | P04083 | ... SV = 2MAMVSEFLK...` (no space between "2" and "MAM").

Comment: Well, I'm looking for an R package that does this, but I haven't found it. In the case of "DEATIIDILTK", I expected "GVDEATIIDILTK" to be returned, for example. As I am not a programmer, I would like to know how to start this type of work. he he

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `str_extract` and positive lookahead:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(dat, "\\w{2} (?=(DEATIIDILTK|DAIPAVEVFEGEPGNK))")
[1] NA    "GV "
```

Data:

```
dat <- c("sp | P30044 | PRDX5_HUMAN Peroxiredoxin-5, mitochondrial OS = Homo sapiens OX = 9606 GN = PRDX5 PE = 1 SV = 4 MGLAGVCALRRSAGYILVGGAGGQSAAAAARRYSEGEWASGGVRSFSRAAAAMAPIKVGD AIPAVEVFEGEPGNKVNLAELFKGKKGVLFGVPGAFTPGCSKTHLPGFVEQAEALKAKGV QVVACLSVNDAFVTGEWGRAHKAEGKVRLLADPTGAFGKETDLLLDDSLVSIFGNRRLKR FSMVVQDGIVKALNVEPDGTGLTCSLAPNIISQL",
         "sp | P04083 | ANXA1_HUMAN Annexin A1 OS = Homo sapiens OX = 9606 GN = ANXA1 PE = 1 SV = 2 MAMVSEFLKQAWFIENEEQEYVQTVKSSKGGPGSAVSPYPTFNPSSDVAALHKAIMVKGV DEATIIDILTKRNNAQRQQIKAAYLQETGKPLDETLKKALTGHLEEVVLALLKTPAQFDA DELRAAMKGLGTDEDTLIEILASRTNKEIRDINRVYREELKRDLAKDITSDTSGDFRNAL LSLAKGDRSEDFGVNEDLADSDARALYEAGERRKGTDVNVFNTILTTRSYPQLRRVFQKY TKYSKHDMNKVLDLELKGDIEKCLTAIVKCATSKPAFFAEKLHQAMKGVGTRHKALIRIM VSRSEIDMNDIKAFYQKMYGISLCQAILDETKGDYEKILVALCGGN")
```

Comment: To me (not the OP), it would make more sense if the lines were concatenated *without* a space, which means the results should be `"VG" "GV"`.